# Im trying to create GoogleCredential by using Service Account JSON,but have a problem

Tags: android, kotlin, google-oauth

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getAccessToken(): String? {
    val googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
        .fromStream(FileInputStream("campusshop-8bbd7-firebase-adminsdk-4j10y-4b35043fe3.json"))
        .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
    googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken()
    return googleCredentials.accessToken.tokenValue
}
```

This is the code to get the token, the whole problem is in `FileInputStream`, no matter what path I pass into it, always the same error `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: service-account.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` file is in the same directory as the file with the code `getAccessToken`

Comment: 1. Make sure the file is in the same directory as your code.   2. make sure the file isn't named campusshop-8bbd7-firebase-adminsdk-4j10y-4b35043fe3.json.json  (yes it happens) 3. make sure your app has access to read the file.

Comment: @DalmTo I checked everything, but unfortunately it did not help